# Meta or JavaScript redirect

Tags: javascript, redirect, internet-explorer-6, meta-tags

I am remodeling a website, I have chosen to redirect the small amount of IE6 users to the old site. I will be redirecting from www.etterengineering.com/booster.html or www.ettterengineering.com/booster_IE6.html.  Is it safe to use a Meta or Javascript redirect or will my original page be black listed in terms of SEO?

Comment: Use Meta....javascript can be blocked by client browsers.

Comment: try http://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

If you have to do it this way then I would suggest META, however for SEO purposes i wouldn't have thought its good practice to have duplicate content specifically for IE6.

What are the reasons for this? You could develop an IE6 only stylesheet? Or you could make use of progressive enchancement.

What are the problems you are experiencing with IE6 - maybe we could help you get over those instead?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any damage done as far as SEO is concerned if its a conditional redirect based on the IE6 browser. Best case scenario you do this server-side with something like PHP and the redirection happens before it reaches the client.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Meta and not JavaScript, as it will provide the best SEO oriented results, search engines would ignore your JS redirect and stay in the redirecting page, on the other hand, by providing meta information, (redirect 301, redirect 302) the search engine will not only move to the new page, but also transfer PageRank and Site popularity to the new site.

I recommend taking a look on [this page](http://www.mcanerin.com/en/articles/301-redirect-scripting.asp), it has very clear explanation on this matter and also some working examples on different languages.

Regards